# How to create an object with JNI?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I need to implement some functions into an Android application using NDK and thus JNI.

Here's the C code, with my concerns, that I wrote:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

jobject
Java_com_example_ndktest_NDKTest_ImageRef(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray myArray)
{
    jint i;
    jobject object;
    jmethodID constructor;
    jobject cls;
    cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/ndktest/NDKTest/Point");

//what should put as the second parameter? Is my try correct, according to what
//you can find in .java file? I used this documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16027

    constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "void(V)");
//http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16660
//Again, is the last parameter ok?

    object = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, constructor, 5, 6);
//I want to assign "5" and "6" to point.x and point.y respectively.
    return object;
}
```

My problems are more or less explained inside the code. Maybe also: is the return type of the function (jobject) ok?

Now the NDKTest.java:

```
package com.example.ndktest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NDKTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public native Point ImageRef(int width, int height, byte[] myArray);
    public class Point
    {

        Point(int myx, int myy)
        {
            x = myx;
            y = myy;
        }

        int x;
        int y;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         TextView tv = new TextView(this);
         byte[] anArray = new byte[3];
         for (byte i = 0; i < 3; i++)
             anArray[i] = i;
         Point point = ImageRef(2, 3, anArray);
         tv.setText(String.valueOf(point.x));
            setContentView(tv);     
    }



    static
    {
       System.loadLibrary("test");
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work".

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Since `Point` is an inner class, the way to get it would be

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/ndktest/NDKTest$Point");
```

The `$` convention for inner classes is not really clearly documented in the authoritative specs, but is entrenched in so much working code that it's unlikely to change. Still, it would *feel* somewhat more robust if you restricted your JNI code to work with top-level classes.

You want a constructor that takes two ints as arguments. The signature for that is `(II)V`, so:

```
constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(II)V");
```

Next time, include some error handling in your code, such that you'll have a clue which part of it doesn't work!

Comment: Note: this answer will not work. See the comments in Seva's answer below for why (constructor arguments must include outer class)

Comment: @Colin: Yeah, I overlooked that `Point` is not static.

Comment: Is it necessary to close/free values returned by FindClass or GetMethodID?

Answer (score 14):

The specification is correct, but a bit misleading in this case. `GetMethodID` requires a method name and a method signature. The [specification says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4517):

> To obtain the method ID of a constructor, supply <init> as the method name and void (V) as the return type.

Note that it says *return type*, not *signature*. Although `void(V)` looks superficially similar to a signature, the specification is telling you that the signature must specify a void (that is, `V`) return type.

The correct signature for a no-argument constructor is `()V`. If the constructor has arguments, they should be described between the parentheses, as other commenters have noted.

Answer (score 7):

Some problems with your code.

First, why are you creating your own Point class rather than using library-provided android.graphics.Point?

Second, the class spec for nested classes is different - it would be "com/example/ndktest/NDKTest$Point". Class nesting is different from packages.

Third, I don't think JNI lets you create instances of nonstatic nested classes. You need to pass the nesting class object' `this` pointer at object creation - there's no such argument.

Finally, while I've seen the guidance to use "void(V)" as a constructor method signature, but this is out of line with the rest of method signatures; normally, a method with two int parameters and void return type would be "(II)V".

As a side note, I found it much cleaner to pass primitive types and arrays of primitive typed from NDK to Java. Object creation/access is messy and hard to debug.

Comment: @Hennig Makholm
I created my own Point class just for example. It could have as been _foo_. I changed my class to be top level, changed "void(V) to "(II)V" and now it works.

Comment: The documentation says: "This ID must be obtained by calling GetMethodID() with <init> as the method name and void (V) as the return type."  I too was confused by this when I first read it; I thought it meant "use the signature `void(V)` but it actually meant "use type code `V` (for void) when you construct the signature".  Sure `void(V)` looks like a weird signature, but then `"<init>"` is a weird way to specify a constructor.  When all is magic anyway, confusing stuff is really confusing!  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

Comment: You can in fact create instances of nonstatic nested classes, the method is just a bit non-obvious: all constructors for the nested class have an implicit first parameter of the outer class's type.  So for the above example, with the Point class non-static, the constructor signature would be `"<init>", "(Lcom/example/ndktest/NDKTest;II)V"`.  You can see this by running `javap -s -p com.example.ndktest.NDKTest$Point` from your classes directory after a build.

Comment: @benkc This comment saved me.  A very important detail.

Answer (score 5):

In JNI you can always use the `javap` tool for finding method signatures. Just run `javap -s com.example.ndktest.NDKTest` and copy the method signatures from the output.

Answer (score 3):

Three steps should create the Point object with JNI:

```
jobject
Java_com_example_ndktest_NDKTest_ImageRef(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray myArray)
{
    ...
    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/ndktest/NDKTest$Point");
    jmethodID constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "void(V)");
    jobject object = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, constructor, obj, 5, 6);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is useful in that it shows a succinct code example. The code will fail though, because the method signature is wrong. It should be `"(II)V"`, as listed in other answers.

Comment: also the `obj, 5, 6`...`obj` is not supposed to be there I believe (assuming signature of `(II)V` like in the question)

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass ( "ISOInfoEx" );
jobject obj = env->AllocObject ( clazz );
```

This will create an object of the class ISOInfoEx. In my case i use it later in code as a structure.