# MimeTeX and Android, using the Native Functions in Android

Tags: java, android, c, latex

:) :) Okay so I am new to LaTeX and Android (So don't hate me please). I am currently working on a project that involves the MimeTeX library working in an android application. (MimeTeX is the LaTeX library ported for android.)

Seeing that MimeTeX is written in C you have to use the native development kit.

I have the following in my main activity:

```
public native subraster rasterize ( char expression, int size );

static 
{
   System.loadLibrary("mimetex");
}
```

Now Eclipse is telling me that 'subraster' cannot be resolved as a type. So can anyone maybe help me and tell me what do I have to add to my MainActivity (in Java) for the subraster type to be valid? I have already configured all the paths and included the ndk-build.cmd to the build path of the C/C++ compiler.

Thank you, and I am sorry, but I am new to this. :) Even links with relevant information would be helpful (If you can find any)

Comment: What is the type of `subraster`? If that's a struct or something more complex than a simple primitive (`int` etc) you'll have to add classes representing that type in Java and construct them in native code. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260376/how-to-create-an-object-with-jni

Comment: Yes it is struct according to the header file. :) Okay thank you, I will look into that. :)