# Problems with int object to integer casting

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-native-interface, integer, int

For a project of mine i am working with the Java Native Interface (JNI).

My project contains a JNI System that calls a function on de C++ side with a port parameter. This function than returns a Object array as written in the comments below, the problem is stated in the last comment:

```
public Integer SpawnNewConnectionHandler(Integer Port) throws WrapperException {
    //Creation of the object array that will hold the result
    Object[] result;

    //Get the result object array from the external library. Length of the array is either 1 or 2.
    //While debugging i found out that it contains two elements of the type int (Not integer, but its basetype).
    //This means that nothing on the c++ side went wrong.
    result = spawnNewServerConnectionHandler(Port);

    //Error coming from the SDK should be handled here. (Code snipped as the if clause checking for it, is not being called.)
    //The snipped will throw a WrapperException if the length of the array returned is not 1.

    //The debugger will break here and show me that before executing this line both of the result objects are not empty,
    //So result[0] and result[1] are filled with data, for result[1] it is a 1 or higher. For result[0] is is the number 0. (Returned as a fact that everything went alright while executing.)
    //During execution of this line the program crashes and shows a NullPointerException.
    //
    //I found out that it is impossible for it to cast the object, stored in the object array as a int into a Integer.
    //Doing this manually while debugging shows the following error message:
    //"Unable to cast numeric value to java.lang.Integer."
    return (Integer) result[1];
}
```

Does anybody know a solution to this problem, or at least why it is giving me this weird error?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `Object[] result` as `int[] result`? I suspect you've got a primitive array, in which case your return would look like `Integer.valueOf(result[1])`.

Comment: sigpwned, i do have a ObjectArray containing Integers that is returned by the external library. If i try to cast that is gives me an error, while compiling, and it says that the two types are incompatible.

Comment: there is a difference between a `int[]` and an `Integer[]` array. Namely, the first is a primitive type, and the second is an object type. Based on your comment below about `{int[2]@2559}`, it's clear you have a primitive array on your hands. Just a moment -- I'll respond with some code I think it would be useful to try.

Comment: Yeah i know, but the conversion does somehow not work, the compilers throws an error complaining about incompatible types, expecting int[] found java.lang.object[].

Answer (score 1):

Casting does not change the type of the object.  In order to cast result[1] to Integer, result[1] must BE an integer already.

You do not say what type of objects are in the array.  I know the array is declared Object, but that means that the objects in the array could be anything, since any object can be a subclass of object.

You say the values in the arrays have values, but you do not say how you know that or what kind of values you have.  The error message you sort-of give doesn't really match your sort-of explanation.  So it's hard to say exactly what is going on.  But you don't have an Integer object to cast, that's why the cast doesn't work.

Comment: While debugging i stop the code before executing the return line and it says result = {int[2]@2559} (the last four numbers change as it is the memory location).

Comment: I agree this appears to be an array of int -- I presume you can return "new Integer(result[1]);"

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to @rcook, it appears that you have an `int[]` array, not an `Integer[]`. The difference here is that `int` is a [primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and `Integer` is an object type.

Try this:

```
public Integer SpawnNewConnectionHandler(Integer Port) throws WrapperException {
    //Creation of the object array that will hold the result
    int[] result;

    //Get the result object array from the external library. Length of the array is either 1 or 2.
    //While debugging i found out that it contains two elements of the type int (Not integer, but its basetype).
    //This means that nothing on the c++ side went wrong.
    result = (int[]) spawnNewServerConnectionHandler(Port);

    //Error coming from the SDK should be handled here. (Code snipped as the if clause checking for it, is not being called.)
    //The snipped will throw a WrapperException if the length of the array returned is not 1.

    //The debugger will break here and show me that before executing this line both of the result objects are not empty,
    //So result[0] and result[1] are filled with data, for result[1] it is a 1 or higher. For result[0] is is the number 0. (Returned as a fact that everything went alright while executing.)
    //During execution of this line the program crashes and shows a NullPointerException.
    //
    //I found out that it is impossible for it to cast the object, stored in the object array as a int into a Integer.
    //Doing this manually while debugging shows the following error message:
    //"Unable to cast numeric value to java.lang.Integer."
    return Integer.valueOf(result[1]);
}
```

Note that I've replaced all references to `Object[]` with `int[]`.

Comment: I tried that, it gives an incompatible type error; expected int[] found java.lang.object[] when i try to compile it.

Comment: Did you write the JNI declaration for `spawnNewServerConnectionHandler()`? If so, you may need to change the declaration return type to `int[]`.

Comment: Yes i wrote the JNI Declaration using javah. And i know it works if i let it return an jIntArray. But that is not solving the problem in the long run. My second JNI function that i need to call after this returns both a string and a integer. Which means that i need to use a object array instead of a int[]. So i thought why not try to implement a general method and use the same system for both.

Comment: That's a very different concern than the one you posted! The code you posted isn't working because you're trying to treat an `int[]` like an `Integer[]`. If you need to know how to create an `Object[]` or an `Integer` in JNI, you may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260376/how-to-create-an-object-with-jni) useful. However, you'd probably be better off returning a custom object that contains a `String` and an `int` rather than an `Object[]`.

Comment: Is it actually possible to do such kind of things with JNI, i mean use custom objects? Hmm that would be a nice concept actually. I will take a look at it thanks for the tip!