# How can i return a jobject if i have a class?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I ran into a problem with return jobject.

I have class:

```
 class KeyPair  {

        std::vector<BYTE> _publicKey;
        std::vector<BYTE> _privateKey;

    public:
        void SetKeys(std::vector<BYTE> publicKey, std::vector<BYTE> privateKey)
        {
            _publicKey = publicKey;
            _privateKey = privateKey;
        };
    };
```

and function:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL function(JNIEnv *env, jobject)
{
    //some code
    KeyPair keyPair;
    keyPair.SetKeys(pub, priv);
    return keyPair;//error
}
```

How can i return keyPair as jobjecct?

Comment: Welcome to JNI. The workflow is to define a Java class, mark some methods as native, run javac to get a .class file, run javah to get a .h file, and then implement the functions in a compatible language based on the .h file. You might find javap -s useful when calling JNI functions. Also, consider SWiG and JNA as JNI tools that do the workflow in the opposite direction. SWiG might serve you best here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast C++ objects to `jobject`s like that.

One approach is to define a Java `KeyPair` class that has a `private long ptr` field into which you stuff a pointer to a C++ `KeyPair` object. It helps if you create a one-argument constructor that fills the `ptr` field with its argument.

To create such a thing: (see also [How to create an object with JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260376/how-to-create-an-object-with-jni]))

- Look up the jclass associated with your java `KeyPair` class (`env->FindClass`).
- Look up the constructor (`env->GetMethodId`).
- Instantiate the object (`env->NewObject`).
- Finally, return the `jobject`.

If you later need to extract the `ptr` from a `KeyPair` passed as `jobject`, you need to look up the field ID for `ptr` and use `env->GetLongField` to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste here the error? 
Actually, you can not return a class - it just doesn't make sense, you always return an object, that is an instance of the class.